# Building magnet uri from torrent hash

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, torrent, magnet-uri

I am reviewing torrent search apis, json ones. I am currently examining **strike api** and **torrent project api**.

In the **strike api** the responses includes **magnet uri**s, but in the **torrent project api** no **magnet uri**s delivered but **torrent_hash** is delivered.

In one of the alternative npm modules I plan to use I need magnet uri to download files. And **torrent project api** is the one that seems more suitable for me.

As I have made a little research on magnet uri scheme and examined the return values from the **strike api**, that include both **torrent hash** and **magnet uri** of the same file, I see the **torrent hash** is included in a **magnet uri** as `xt` (exact topic) parameter including `urn` as `xt=urn:btih:<torrent_hash_here>`, for BitTorrent downloads.

However, other info than **torrent hash** also included in a **magnet uri**, trackers in `tr` parameters. These are more general tracker adresses.

Is it possible to correctly build the **magnet uri** of a file from its **torrent hash**?

If yes, how, by just string concatenation? What about the trackers (values of `tr` parameters in **magnet uri**), where to find them for adding to string built as **magnet uri**?

Is that actually necessary to download files? Can files be downloaded by use of **torrent hash**es without **magnet uri**s? If yes, how?

an example magnet uri key from a **strike api** response:

```
magnet_uri":"magnet:?xt=urn:btih:B425907E5755031BDA4A8D1B6DCCACA97DA14C04&dn=Arch+Linux+2015.01.01+%28x86%2Fx64%29&tr=udp:\/\/open.demonii.com:1337&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969&tr=udp:\/\/tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969&tr=udp:\/\/exodus.desync.com:6969
```

an example response from the **torrent project api**:

`{"total_found":"563690","1":{"title":"Force, Marie et al. -Ask Me Why.epub","category":"ebooks","seeds":5,"leechs":0,"torrent_size":1005221,"torrent_hash":"63a4ca7a1f7796e5ecdc09bac1f8bc69daf3f7eb"}}`

Answer (score -4):

> Is it possible to correctly build the magnet uri of a file from its torrent hash?

yes

> Can files be downloaded by use of torrent hashes without magnet uris?

yes